# Recommendations to fix work overwritten in a bad merge

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Consider the following situation:

git configuration has `rerere.enabled 1`, enabling resolution recording and replay. The following commit history exists:

```
  B
 / \
A---C---E master 
 \   \ / 
  D   D'
```

1. Commit `B` was merged in `master` with `--no-ff` to create commit `C`.
2. Commit `B` and `D` contain conflicting modifications to a file `Foo`.
3. Commit `D` was rebased to `C` creating commit `D'` - the conflict in `Foo` was erroneously resolved by taking the changes in `D` only. The correct resolution would have included changes from both `B` and `D`.
4. Commit `D'` was merged into master to create commit `E`, and changes to `Foo` due to commit `B` were lost without conflict.
5. A later inspection revealed the mistake. A attempt to recover was performed by executing `git cherry-pick B` on `master` with the intention of being able to manually resolve the conflict correctly using a mergetool. However, rerere kicks in and replays the bad resolution. No `git rerere` invocations seem to be able to show or clear the bad resolution.

What's the best way to deal with this situation? Is it a bug in git that cherry-pick has no rerere override (I am on version 2.9.2)? It feels like something that would crop up often, yet I can't find examples of it being addressed in the documentation (which may be poor searching on my part).

Bear in mind this is a vastly simplified commit tree. In reality there were dozens more commits along the way between those shown, over the period of several days - but the essence of what happened is as captured above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, but is there a better way?

It seems that there is no equivalent to the `git merge --no-rerere-autoupdate` for `git cherry-pick`. The best way I could think of to get around this was to temporarily apply `git config --local --add rerere.enabled 0`, which worked - that is I could then `git cherry-pick B` without the automatic resolution and then use `git mergetool` to resolve the conflict. This is a bit of a pain - especially as you have to remember to undo the config setting afterwards, but it does have the advantage of presenting the correct merge base in the diff tool.

Another approach I tried was to use `git checkout B .` (note the dot) to grab the changes into the index, and use `git difftool --cached` to edit `Foo` in my diff tool. Whilst this works and is less steps, it doesn't give you the merge base to work from in the diff.